# Does anyone agree with Rebbe Nachman that the Tikkun HaKlali is a teshuvah for all sins?

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, breslov, repentance-teshuvah

Rebbe Nachman of Breslov Zt"l apparently recommended reciting [a series of ten psalms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikkun_HaKlali)--plus several interpolated prayers--as a teshuvah for any sin, and particularly the questionable sin of involuntary nocturnal emission. I am wondering if there are any authorities outside of Breslov who agree that this so-called "Tikkun HaKlali" is in fact an appropriate atonement for any sin. (I had been thinking of trying to use it for missed davening.)

Comment: The only way to do teshuva for any sin is regret having sinned, confess the sin orally to God, ask forgiveness from any party harmed, and commit to not doing it again. It's a deceptively simple process

Comment: @DoubleAA Source?

Comment: Rambam Teshuva 1:1. This is basic Judaism.

Comment: @DoubleAA I wasn't aware that Rambam=normative halacha in every case (or even close)

Comment: I wasn't either.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Rabbeinu Yonah has a much longer list, but it includes those four. I would argue the four steps the Rambam gives was proven authoritative not by the Rambam, but by the centuries of "peer review" since. Which is why everyone repeats it as basic Judaism. (Much the way the 13 Articles of Faith are authoritative -- AS THEY APPEAR IN THE SIDDUR. The Rambam and his original did not define Jewish belief as much as what we did with his idea.)

Comment: @MichaBerger I don't see how those are parallel at all, but this isn't really the place to discuss that. Either way RY doesn't include saying random chapters of Psalms, if I'm not mistaken, even if we can quibble about other parts of the process.

Comment: In any case, the idea that prayer is the central piece to teshuvah, not correcting the sin, trying to do better, or even confessing it, is -- I believe -- part of R' Nachman's novellum. A bigger novellum is that R' Nachman promises to intercede; he does not claim the prayer helps directly! (R' Nachman's Wisdom #141) Intersessionary saints is considered heresy in a lot of circles.  I am betting that the final answer to this one is going to be "no other authorities".

Comment: Details about Tiqun haKlali that I think the question gets wrong: (1) Those other prayers are later than R' Nachman, and therefore I believe not part the actual tiqun. (2) An important part is to give tzedaqah, even if only the smallest coin.

Comment: Tikkun Haklali is not teshuva, even Rabbi Nachman knowed this. Teshuva is described in halacha. Read tehilim is not teshuva. Teshuva is a little harder.

Answer (score 1):

The [Shomrei Emunim Rebbe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_Roth) in his sefer [Taharos Hakodesh](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41665&st=&pgnum=337) says that it was revealed to Rav Nachman from Heaven that the 10 psalms are for rectifying involuntary nocturnal emissions. Which kinds of sounds like it excludes other possibilities.

Comment: Who is the Shomer Emunim?

Comment: And not every sin

Comment: Sorry @ShmuelBrin, I meant Shomrei Emunim. Fixed it. Its Rav Ahron Roth zt"l, the author of the more famous sefer Shomer Emunim.

Comment: But according to R' Nachman, the flaw in Yesod (the sephirah in which humans corresponds to the reproductive organ/s) is the keystone which holds together all other sin. Fix this, and the "other side" loses all hold. (Liqutei Moharan 1:29)

Comment: A friend told me that he looked into this topic a while back, and found Rav Chaim Palagi (Haim Palachi on Wikipedia) brings Rav Nachman's tikkun klali and highly praises it. He doesn't remember in which sefer the reference appears. It also seemed like it was Rav Nachman's chidush, but that it was accepted by mekubalim.

Comment: Prob in Refuos Vchaim @Binyomin